# Can't open PowerPoint doc in read only or edit view only opens in EI view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am new to SP only use it to upload documents; however, in two instances (today being one) of them I am unable to get the option to view as Read Only or Edit it simply says Open or Save and when I click on Open it opens the PowerPoint in Explorer view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in order to open (view/edit) Office documents (word, Powerpoint, OneNote) you nee d Office Web Apps add-in installed and configured on your farm. For Excel, you need Excel Services, which comes with the Enterprise License, not part of the OWA.

Now, besides this, there is a site Collection level feature which must be switched on/off depending on your need - "Open Documents in Client Applications by Default"!!

Answer (score 0):

Library settings --> Advanced settings and then choose what you want the applications to open with.

[image]